# How to prevent highlighting of <a> tag in HTML?

Tags: html, css, jsx

Text inside `<a>` tag is blue and underlined. How to switch it off? I use JSX.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:css] and this is pretty basic CSS.

Comment: 2nd time this was asked today. Random. lol

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple question.
All you need to do is add CSS on the  tag.

```
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
```

& if you want to use it in React it can go in the style tag like so

```
style={{
textDecoration: 'none',
color: 'black'}}
```

Comment: That CSS is invalid.